# Sources prohibiting Mi Sheberachs on Shabbos

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, shabbat, money, torah-service

There are a couple of potential reasons to perhaps avoid saying Mi Sheberachs for Cholim or people who get Aliyos during Leining on Shabbos ([Tircha Detzibura](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/41249/what-are-the-parameters-of-tircha-dtzibbur) and [Pesikas Mammon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/sale-of-kibbudim-on-shabbat-chag)).  However, whether due to Minhag or otherwise, many Poskim are lenient (see above links), and allow such Mi Sheberachs to be recited.

I am looking for sources in Halacha that **directly prohibit** saying either one (or both) of these Misheberachs on Shabbos for one of the two reasons above.

Comment: @Double AA Perhaps this is not a duplicate because the other question appears to be limited too the issue of praying for the ill on Shabbos, whereas this question seems to be about any potential issue with saying Mi shebeirach (and even mentions a non-choleh Mi Shebeirach)?

Comment: @Alex I hear you, but if we have a question about A, and another about A and B, we can't leave the second open just because it also asks about B. The A part of it should be edited out or, better, edited to be a premise in light of the conclusion to the first question. Leaving it open about A and B leads to unnecessary time spent answering the A component, which is what duplicate-ness is primarily trying to avoid

Comment: @DoubleAA It was edited, please cast your magical last vote if you feel it is now different enough...

Comment: What about a posek who prohibits for an entirely different reason?

Comment: @Alex sorry, but I can't allow that as an answer.  (site rules lol)

Comment: @רבותמחשבות  If you were open to other reasons you could edit the question. My question was essentially "are you really only looking for these two reasons and no others?"

Comment: @alex no, but if I open it up to other reasons, it can be reclosed.

Comment: (Reclosed? It hasn't even been reopened yet.) You could ask if there are any reasons besides praying for the sick (and perhaps even link @DoubleAA's answer from the other question).

Comment: Does Yaavetz [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1408&st=&pgnum=93) (siman 64) give you what you're looking for?